# How to free the allocated memory in GUI application?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, malloc

I have a GUI application which is written in C/gtk+(v 2.x). If I clicked on a menu item of the main window, following function will get called and will show a dialog.

```
dialog_ui * create_dialog ()
{
    dlg = malloc (sizeof(dialog_ui));
    dlg->window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    ...
    gtk_widget_show_all (dlg->window);
    return dlg;
}
```

This is the `dialog_ui` structue

```
typedef struct _dialog_ui
{
    GtkWidget * window;
    ...
} dialog_ui;
```

This is the `dlg` variable in the header file.

```
dialog_ui * dlg;
```

My problem is, i'm calling the `malloc` in the `create_dialog` function. But I can't figure out from where can I call `free`, because GUI is event driven. I thought about `destroy-event`, but I want to know the correct way to do this. Any ideas.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times you have a modal dialog which you call using `gtk_dialog_run()` rather than `gtk_widget_show()`. The `gtk_dialog_run()` function will not return until the user closes the dialog, returning a response which you can use to determine if they clicked Yes, Ok, Cancel, Close, etc. You an see an example of that in the [GtkDialog API documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-run).

Since you're just showing your own `GtkWindow`, your main application code could connect to the `"destroy"` signal of the `GtkWindow` and free the struct that references the widget there.

As a side note, rather than using `malloc`, you may want to take a look at some of the [Memory Allocation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Memory-Allocation.html) functions provided by `GLib`.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need the dialog anymore, and you're not going to access it anymore (for example when it's closed) you can free the allocated memory. Doing it in the destroy event is a good place.