# How to properly free allocated memory in a GTK app

Tags: c, gtk

I have to malloc an array of C structs in my Linux GTK application which will be needed for the entire duration of the app.
Since I'm using custom C structs this precludes using Glib functions like [g_slice_alloc and g_slice_free1](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/memory-slices.html)

Where would be the ideal place to free() the malloc'd memory? A poster suggested connecting to the [destroy signal of a GTK Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029126/how-to-free-the-allocated-memory-in-gui-application), but 1) what if the app is terminated via a SIGINT signal or SIGTERM, and 2) isn't it better to use the destroy signal of the application?

Conversely, if I put the free() in a sighandler, then perhaps the simple act of clicking on the 'x' of a window would not free my memory.

Comment: Why do you want to free memory when your app is closing? It all just goes away along with your process anyway.